# Return enum value guidelines

Tags: enums

Say you have all your functions return a result-status (just like Microsoft's HRESULT). These numbers are defined in an enum with one value indicating that everything is OK, and all other values indicate some flavor of NOT OK.

Intuitively I number OK = 0 and all others !=0. But, if you are a C programmer (and several other languages) than this is just the opposite of bool.

I've started wondering if there are any programming guide-lines around this. What is the general practice? What are the pros and cons? This because I've become involved in a project where OK = 0x01 and all other fail-states are !0x01 (yes 0x0 is also a fail), and we are marshaling return-values between languages (enums become ints).

Comment: it wouldn't be microsoft if they did it like normal people ;-)

Comment: I believe it comes from program exit statuses - 0 for ok and everything else for non-ok. And it isn't so opposite to bool - what (bool)9 would be, in logic context?

Answer (score 0):

if zero is no error, and anything else is an error then you can write

```
error = function_that_returns_an_error();

if( error )
    handleError();
```

or

```
if( !error )
    allsWell();
```

Which is quite clear code

Aside, sometimes negative values are error codes, and positive values are status codes (for example "need more data", and then zero is alls well